# how to create negative numbers in array by loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'd like to know how to create an array like the following with a for loop (notice that the accepted answer includes 0 while it was not part of my requirements. I guess I should meditate on this and stop ignoring people's comments).

```
var arr = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

My try can't print the negative numbers in array.

```
for (var i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

Result:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I also don't want the negative numbers of indexes in the array.

```
arr[-10]....arr[-9].....arr[1]...
```

Comment: You do not have a 0 in the desired final array.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Answer the comments next time please Allen. Thanks.

Comment: If you care about performances read this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546391/how-to-create-negative-numbers-in-array-by-loop/32546509#comment52950406_32546509.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
for (var j = -10; j <= 10; j++)
    arr[arr.length] = j;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you push to the array, you don't have to state the index:

```
var i, arr = [];
for (i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
```

If you need to skip 0:

```
for (i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
    i !== 0 && arr.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    arr [i] = i - 10;
}
```

Indexes in an array always starts from 0 and can't be negative so if you need negative values at positive indexes some computations or translation of values must take place.

Comment: You need to go up to 20

Answer (score 2):

> As I don't see `0` in question:

```js
var arr = [];
for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
 arr.push(j);
 arr.unshift((j) * (-1)); 
}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide the desired sequence of -10 to -1 then 1 to 10 without the 0, consider the following:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = -10; i < 0; i++) arr[i + 10] = i;
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) arr[i + 10] = i;
```

If you want to use the same loop with a different range, just define a variable to replace 10 every time you see it in the code given above.

Comment: There is an addition for each iteration :-| I wonder if your answer would be more interesting if you set the size of the array like this: `arr = new Array(21)`. I have no idea if it makes any difference in JS, maybe less memory manipulations since there is no need to resize (?). If we can set the size this way there must be a good reason x-)

Comment: Maybe @mplungjan can give some more commentary on inefficiency.  I fixed the `var arr = []` definition.  The answer that uses `arr.push` seems to be just as efficient as this one, albeit slightly more elegant.

Comment: It seems that my intuition was right, as far as jsperf.com is reliable: http://jsperf.com/array-fixed-size-vs-resizing. Then, you could replace `var arr = []` with `var arr = new Array(20)` to make your code more efficient :-)

Comment: My intuition is more interesting than I thought. Apparently, the performances are almost the same using `arr.push(i)`, `arr[arr.length] = i` and `arr[i + 10] = i`, which is not so surprising after all... But you would win using a fixed size, 2 times faster! Check: http://jsperf.com/so-a-32546509-1636522 :-D

Comment: Well, 2 times faster in Chrome actually, the difference is less significant in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var array = new Array();
var arrayIndex = 0;

for(var i=-10; i<=10;i++){
  array[arrayIndex++] = i;
}
```

Array indexes start at 0 and cannot be negative.

**Explanation:**

The first line declares the array.

The second line declares a variable named `arrayIndex`.

The `for` loop iterates through all the numbers ranging between -10 to 10 and assigning all those values from `array[0]` to `array[20]`

Comment: Maybe is harder to grasp this way until how indexes work is not clear enough.